# Exception in Application start method java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: javafx, scene-builder

Создал свой первый javaFX проект.  Наткнулся на распространённую ошибку, но не все ее могут решить (я в том числе). Fxml файл делал с помощью JavaFX Scene Builder 18.0.0

```
package com.example.firstjavafx;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(HelloApplication.class.getResource("menu.fxml"));  //Здесь пробовал писать menu/fxml не помогло
        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 320, 240);
        stage.setTitle("Hello!");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

Контролер

```
package com.example.firstjavafx;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class ControllerMenu {
    @FXML
    private Label welcomeText;

    @FXML
    protected void onHelloButtonClick() {
        welcomeText.setText("Welcome to JavaFX Application!");
    }
}
```

fxml файл

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.Cursor?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>

<fx:root maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" style="-fx-background-color: #483D8B;" type="AnchorPane" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/17" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.example.firstjavafx.ControllerMenu">
   <children>
      <AnchorPane layoutY="113.0" prefHeight="286.0" prefWidth="600.0" style="-fx-background-color: #DCDCDC;">
         <children>
            <Button fx:id="garantButton" ellipsisString="%95" layoutX="114.0" layoutY="118.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="133.0" text="Расчет Гаранта">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="14.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button fx:id="VkladButton" ellipsisString="%95" layoutX="357.0" layoutY="118.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Вклад в чужое ВС">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="14.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
         </children>
         <cursor>
            <Cursor fx:constant="OPEN_HAND" />
         </cursor>
      </AnchorPane>
      <Text fill="#18ef00" layoutX="151.0" layoutY="62.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Калькулятор FOE">
         <font>
            <Font name="MV Boli" size="38.0" />
         </font>
      </Text>
   </children>
</fx:root>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ошибка

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.1\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=1644:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-controls\17.0.1\javafx-controls-17.0.1.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-graphics\17.0.1\javafx-graphics-17.0.1.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-base\17.0.1\javafx-base-17.0.1.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-fxml\17.0.1\javafx-fxml-17.0.1.jar -p C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-fxml\17.0.1\javafx-fxml-17.0.1-win.jar;C:\Users\Admin\Documents\dima\MyProjectJava\FirstJavaFx\target\classes;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-graphics\17.0.1\javafx-graphics-17.0.1-win.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-base\17.0.1\javafx-base-17.0.1-win.jar;C:\Users\Admin\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-controls\17.0.1\javafx-controls-17.0.1-win.jar -m com.example.firstjavafx/com.example.firstjavafx.HelloApplication
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:465)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1071)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:901)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: Root hasn't been set. Use method setRoot() before load.
/C:/Users/Admin/Documents/dima/MyProjectJava/FirstJavaFx/target/classes/com/example/firstjavafx/menu.fxml:9

    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2703)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$RootElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1335)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:757)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2808)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2634)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2516)
    at com.example.firstjavafx/com.example.firstjavafx.HelloApplication.start(HelloApplication.java:14)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:847)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:484)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:457)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:456)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application com.example.firstjavafx.HelloApplication
```

Учу java недавно, так что ответ "внимательно посмотри" и т.д. не устраивает :)

Answer (score 0):

Label c id "welcomeText" и  action onHelloButtonClick отсутствуют в fxml.